# How to show a dialog from another dialog?

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I am newbie to MFC. I have a native C++ MFC app. I want to show a dialog from main dialog. In the main dialog I am having three button (Back, Next, Cancel) respectively.
On the Next button click event I am calling DoModal to show another dialog by hiding the main dialog as follows,

```
void CFirstPage::OnBnNextButton()
{
    ::ShowWindow(this->GetSafeHwnd(),SW_HIDE);
    CSecondPage secondDlg;
    secondDlg.DoModal();
}
void CSecondPage::OnBnBackBtnClicked()
{
    ::ShowWindow(this->GetSafeHwnd(),SW_HIDE);
    CFirstPage FirstPage;
    FirstPage.DoModal();
}
```

After executing this code snippet, the main dialog got hidden and even the application icon also disappears from the taskbar and again appears when the other dialog pops up.
(Basically I am having the same icon for both the dialogs, the icon should not get disappeared and appear again. It has to remain same without appearing and disappearing .)

How can show the icon in the taskbar without any flickering effect?

During traversing from back to next in middle I clicked cancel and the Cancel event is handled as follows,

```
void CFirstPage::OnCancel()
{
    CDialog::EndDialog(TRUE);//For closing the dialog.
}
void CSecondPage::OnCancel()
{
    CDialog::EndDialog(TRUE);//For closing the dialog.
}
```

Steps1:Click Next in the main dialog

Step2: Click Cancel in the second page

Now the application closes. But still instance is active in the "TaskManager". As per my understanding no instance should be alive once windows is closed ?
I suspect as the first dialog is only hidden not ended that instance is still existing in the TaskManager. Is this understanding correct?

How can I resolve this issue?

Can anyone kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you want to create a wizard style property sheet, don't invent your own. Use the [CPropertySheel Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3fkt014.aspx) provided by MFC. A property sheet is converted to a wizard by calling [CPropertySheet::SetWizardMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1sse9730.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable , As you suggested it's a very good idea and tried it already and the problem I was facing with propertysheet is  it is getting resized in  DBCS operating systems (Ex:Japanese,Chinese,Taiwanese etc., ). So, that is why I was looking at dialog application(What I noticed in dialog based application is it is not getting resized in so called DBCS Operating systems). If there exists any solution in properysheet kindly let me know.

Comment: you could override CWnd::OnSize for propertysheet and handle resize yourself.

Comment: @Izzy Handling OnSize in propertysheet? As I am loading pages in App class InitInstance how can I resize all pages in Onsize of propertysheet or do you mean to do OnSize in all page derived classes? Can please let me know where and how for all pages it can be done. Give me a bit explanation please.

Comment: I would create derived class based on CPropertySheet, change override OnSize (WM_SIZE event from ClassWizard). Property pages are jut dialog boxes, and during initialization WM_SIZE will be called, which you will catch with OnSize handler. The harder part is if you need to move and resize controls to match your new layout.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Iinspectable property sheets are best suited for your your problem statement.A very good example on how to use [CPropertysheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3fkt014.aspx) can be found in codeproject
[CProperty sheet example](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/propertysheet/article.php/c605/Update-Creating-a-full-application-using-the-CPropertySheet.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your main windows is still hidden after you end dialog with second page. Ending dialog of CSecondPage does not close application only closes active CSecondPage dialog.

Also OnCancel/OnOK does not need to be overriden if you just EndDialog with it. There is default behaviour implemented in OnCancel, which will close the dialog.

After secondPage.DoModal() show your main dialog again, or close it if that is the behaviour you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

`FirstPage` isn't the original first dialog now, so you should store the first dialog object by yourself. You can do that like this:

```
void CFirstPage::OnBnNextButton()
{
::ShowWindow(this->GetSafeHwnd(),SW_HIDE);
CSecondPage secondDlg;
secondDlg.setFirstDialog(this);   //customer function to store first dialig object
secondDlg.DoModal();
}

void CSecondPage::OnBnBackBtnClicked()
{
::ShowWindow(this->GetSafeHwnd(),SW_HIDE);
::ShowWindow(m_firstDialog->GetSafeHwnd(), SW_SHOW);
}
```